# while scraping a website the null values got parsed as 'N/A' string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, null

I parsed a table data from a website using python the values that were NULL in the website table were fetched as N/A in python. 
`df=pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,9), index=[0])`
But while analyzing the stored data to find null values using `df.isnull().sum()`  shows no null value. but these are present in the dataset.

I think that the null values have been parsed as a string. how can I make these values count as null. 
THank you.

Comment: what function are you using to create df?

Comment: @ChrisA edited the question

Comment: Several of the `pandas.read_xxx` functions take an argument `na_values`. You could try experimenting with that. ie `na_values=['N/A']` .... although I believe this value should actually be one of the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be a quick fix:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = df.replace('N/A', np.nan)
```